Spell Data to Long in R
I have spell data that includes an ID, a group indicator and the length of the spell.
> d <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, 
+            group = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = T), 
+            spell_length = sample(1:3,10, replace = T))


> head(d)
  ID group spell_length
   1     b            1
   2     a            1
   3     a            3
   4     b            1
   5     a            1
   6     b            2

The goal is to reshape the data into a long format with 4 variables: ID, group, time (which runs from 1 to the spell_length) and indicator (0,1) whether the ID is still present in that spell (e.g., if the spell_length is 1, the ID should not be present in time 2 and 3).
ID group  time indicator
 1     b     1        1
 1     b     2        0
 1     b     3        0
 2     a     1        1
 2     a     2        0
 2     a     3        0
 3     a     1        1
 3     a     2        1
 3     a     3        1
 


What have you tried? Where do issues arise?

Do you want reframe like below?
d %>%
    reframe(time = 1:3, indicator = +(1:3 <= spell_length), .by = c(ID, group))

such that
   ID group time indicator
1   1     b    1         1
2   1     b    2         0
3   1     b    3         0
4   2     a    1         1
5   2     a    2         0
6   2     a    3         0
7   3     a    1         1
8   3     a    2         1
9   3     a    3         1
10  4     b    1         1
11  4     b    2         0
12  4     b    3         0
13  5     a    1         1
14  5     a    2         0
15  5     a    3         0
16  6     b    1         1
17  6     b    2         1
18  6     b    3         0

